# Java Application server; which is better?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I need to implement a SOAP Web service. 
with many clients (over 4000 user online).

Service function is a DB access, and other web service access...

Which application server is better. 
Glashfish, Weblogic, Oracle Application Server ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you first implement the Web service on an app server that you're experienced with (or a free one, like Glassfish or JBoss) and then stress test it. If you make it app. server agnostic, porting it to others, including the commercial ones, shouldn't be a problem.

It's usually best to just try out stuff like this for yourself because benchmarks won't always point you to the right direction.

Comment: Thanks i try Glassfish free version.